# Header text outside of the accordion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try to use an accordion component from Bootstrap 4 library. It's work fine. But if header will contain a vary long title like this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque debitis aliquid numquam iure saepe eum, unde hic eligendi quisquam, neque dolorem officia magnam. Aut recusandae ipsam doloribus, cumque alias eum.
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    ...

</div>
```

It goes out of the container boundary.

[image]

How can I trahsfer text to a new line?

I cut example to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9o8g427/12/)

Comment: Add h5 > button { white-space: unset!important; } to your CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
.card button{
  white-space:normal;
}
```

to your css

You are getting that issue because, the the button style contains `white-space:nowrap`

You need to override it by adding above css

JSFiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/eodwvy0t/)

Comment: Thank you. So easy way. Also should add to css `text-align: left` because, the `.btn` style `text-align: center` and it looks weird.